# C# accessing property values by property name

Tags: c#, mongodb

Asked a question earlier, but I didn't word it well enough. I need to access property names in a Mongo db builders projection instantiation.

Versus coding out every single possibility I wanted to access the property via a user choice. Like this

```
   UserSubmittedModel s = new UserSubmittedModel
    {
      SensorDataChannelName = "AirTemp"
    };

  var projection = Builders<SensorData>.Projection.Include(u => u.GetType().GetProperty(s.SensorDataChannelName).GetValue(u, null)).Include(u => u.MainFileId).Include(u => u.UnixTime).Exclude(u => u.Id);
```

However, I repeatedly run into this error when I do this

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to determine the serialization information for u => u.GetType().GetProperty(value(Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_1).s.SensorDataChannelName).GetValue(u, null).'
```

I've also looked deeply at another post involving this where they return from a method, essentially the same thing. But I get the same results.

```
 static object GetPropValue(object target, string? propName)
{
   return target.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(target, null);
}
```

I want convert a user selection into the model param name, so I can project and include it.

Comment: Are you try to pass the value of `s.SensorDataChannelName` to `.Include()`. If yes, I think you can attempt with `.Include(s.SensorDataChannelName)`.

Comment: Think this question can combine with [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71512703/how-to-dynamically-build-mongodb-builders-projections) as both questions aim for the same purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71512703/how-to-dynamically-build-mongodb-builders-projections), I think that you are trying to get the property name from `SensorData` based on the selected value (`s.SensorDataChannelName`).

From the [MongoDB .NET Driver documentation (Projection Definition Builder section)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71512703/how-to-dynamically-build-mongodb-builders-projections), you can pass the field name as `string`, which is an alternative to the lambda expression.

```cs
var projection = Builders<Widget>.Projection.Include("X")
    .Include("Y")
    .Exclude("Id");
```

With this line:

```cs
u.GetType().GetProperty(s.SensorDataChannelName).GetValue(u, null)
```

It returns the value of `u./* value of s.SensorDataChannelName */` but not the property (name) in `u`.

---

Either you can straight pass the field name as below:

```cs
var projection = Builders<SensorData>.Projection
    .Include(s.SensorDataChannelName)
    // Following fields to be included / excluded
    ;
```

Or if you want to validate the property name first:

```cs
string fieldName = typeof(SensorData).GetProperty(s.SensorDataChannelName)?.Name;

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldName))
{
    // TO-DO Handle Invalid field name
    return;
}

var projection = Builders<SensorData>.Projection
    .Include(fieldName)
    .Include(u => u.MainFileId)
    .Include(u => u.UnixTime)
    .Exclude(u => u.Id);
```

Comment: Yong Shun, Thank you. This was incredibly helpful. I've looked over tons of Mongo documentation and I just missed being able to pass the field name as a string. I was so stuck on using the Lambda expression, I didn't see another way out.  Thanks for the clarity on GetType and GetProperty. I'm new to using those methods and wasn't sure what I should be seeing.